# Lorentz algebra elements

Tags: lie-groups, lie-algebras

The matrix of generators is written as,
$\begin{pmatrix}
M^{00} & M^{01} & M^{02} & M^{03}\\
M^{10} & M^{11} & M^{12} & M^{13}\\
M^{20} & M^{21} & M^{22} & M^{23}\\ 
M^{30} & M^{31} & M^{32} & M^{33}\\ 
\end{pmatrix}=
\begin{pmatrix}
0 & K^1 & K^2 & K^3\\
-K^1 & 0 & J^3 & -J^2\\
-K^2 & -J^3 & 0 & J^1\\ 
-K^3 & J^2 & -J^1 & 0\\ 
\end{pmatrix}
$

where $J^i$ are the rotation generators and $K^i$ are the boost generators.

1)

I'm struggling top see how this can be compactly written as, 
$(M^{\mu\nu})^\alpha{}_\beta=i (g^{\mu\alpha}g^{\nu}{}_\beta-g^{\nu\alpha}g^\mu{}_\beta)$.

For instance, I am trying to write out the $\mu=2$, $\nu=0$ case of the matrix,

$\begin{eqnarray*}
(M^{20})^\alpha{}_\beta &=& i (g^{2\alpha}g^{0}{}_\beta-g^{0\alpha}g^2{}_\beta) \\
&=& i(g^{22}g^{0}{}_0-g^{00}g^2{}_2) \\
&=& \begin{pmatrix}
i & 0 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 0 & i & 0\\ 
0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\ 
\end{pmatrix}
\end{eqnarray*}$

but this cannot be right, it does not look like any of the Lorentz algebra elements.

Bonus question:

2) I am trying to see one obtains the operator representation of the $M^{\mu\nu}$ generators, $M^{\mu\nu}=i(x^\mu\partial^\nu - x^\nu \partial^\mu)$.

Thoughts?

Comment: For the Lie algebra $\mathfrak{so}(3,1)$ see [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lorentz_group).

Comment: I have read through this previously, but can't find mention of the generators I mention above. Can you point to an explicit section?

Comment: The section is called "Lie algebra" and has the skew-symmetric $4\times 4$ matrices for the "Lorentz Lie algebra". This is what you are looking for, right?

Comment: Hmm no, sorry. Allow me to expound on my question above with editing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I 'll just illustrate using your conventions, which I strongly suspect are in "east coast signature" (-,+,+,+), spacelike (atrocious! distinctly disadvantaged for momentum space in particle physics...),  which [WP follows](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Representation_theory_of_the_Lorentz_group#Explicit_formulas), arguably consistently.

$$
(M^{20})^\alpha{}_\beta =-(M^{02})^\alpha{}_\beta = -(K^{2})^\alpha{}_\beta= \\
=-i (g^{2\alpha}g^{0}{}_\beta-g^{0\alpha}g^2{}_\beta) \\
= -i\begin{pmatrix}
0 & 0 & 1 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
1 & 0 & 0 & 0\\ 
0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\ 
\end{pmatrix}  ~.
$$

I suspect there are - signs flying around, on account of signatures changing coast during transcription. The crucial thing for you to consider is that $g^{0\alpha}=-1$
giving a net -sign in the 0th row, 2nd column entry, so a net *symmetric matrix*, as, of course, you should be having for boosts.

My overall correction of your formula to 
$$
(M^{\mu\nu})^\alpha{}_\beta=-i (g^{\mu\alpha}g^{\nu}{}_\beta-g^{\nu\alpha}g^\mu{}_\beta)
$$
also agrees with   $M^{\mu\nu}=i(x^\mu\partial^\nu - x^\nu \partial^\mu)$,
so that 
$$
 M^{20 }=i(x^2\partial^0 - x^0 \partial^2)= -i(x^2\partial_0 + x^0 \partial_2),
$$
which sends the vector $(x^0,x^1,x^2,x^3   )^T$ to $-i(x^2,0,x^0,0)^T$, just like the above matrix does.

Comment: Wow, sir. Just wow. Thank you so much for clearing that up for me!  Especially what the "operator representation" did in that last part of your answer. Have no fear, (+,-,-,-) metric over here ;)

Comment: Of course, but I'm hit with the Stack Exchange "Thanks for the feedback! Votes cast by those with less than 15 reputation are recorded, but do not change the publicly displayed post score." ;) give me another day or two and to stumble onto another question and hopefully get up to 15 :D

Comment: Ah... had forgotten about that...